# PowerShell 5.1 handling sql server nvarchar datatype

Tags: powershell

I am loading a DataTable with data from SQL Server as such:

```
$queryStr = "SELECT TOP 10 ID, QueryText FROM dbo.DatabaseName";
$dataRows = Invoke-DbaQuery -SqlInstance instance.name -Database databasename -Query $queryStr -As DataSet;
```

In SQL Server the QueryText is nvarchar(max). In PowerShell, this becomes a string datatype, equal to varchar I think. I think this because when I try to calculate the hash in PowerShell with `Get-FileHash`, and in SQL Server I calculate the hash on the nvarchar column with `SELECT (CONVERT([varchar](70),hashbytes('SHA2_256', QueryText),(1)))`, the hashes do not match.

They DO match however, if I convert the nvarchar to a varchar(max) in SQL Server.

So the question is, in PowerShell how can I convert the string datatype to match the nvarchar datatype in SQL Server? Because as far as I know, PowerShell does not have a nvarchar datatype, just the generic string datatype.

---

Added this part after reading comments.

In the DataTable that I retrieve from SQL Server as per the above code I add an extra column to hold the hash that I calculate in PowerShell.

Add extra column to DataTable:

```
$HashColumn = [System.Data.DataColumn]::new('QueryHashString', [string]);
$dataRows.Tables[0].Columns.Add($HashColumn);
```

Now I do a foreach to fill this column I just added:

```
foreach($row in $dataRows.Tables[0]) {
    $stringAsStream = [System.IO.MemoryStream]::new()
    $writer = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new($stringAsStream)
    $writer.write("$($row.QueryText)")
    $writer.Flush()
    $stringAsStream.Position = 0
    $row.QueryHashString = (Get-FileHash -InputStream $stringAsStream | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Hash)
}
```

Comment: Make sure you are comparing hashes for bit-by-bit identical strings. Hashing a file includes byte order mark (if present) and line might have an extra linefeed terminator too.

Comment: PowerShell's `string` is the .NET `String` type, which internally uses UTF-16, so no, this is not equivalent to `VARCHAR`.  But this is not relevant as long as the characters are retrieved correctly -- the real question is what encoding ends up used when the hash is calculated, because this involves converting the string to bytes. What does your `Get-FileHash` invocation look like? I suspect you ultimately end up using the system default encoding, which by happenstance is probably going to match the default database collation as well (ISO 8859-1 and/or Windows-1252).

Comment: Reading between the lines, you’re writing the string to a text file - can you show how you’re doing this as it will affect the bytes that are written to disk, and *that’s* what you’re hashing with ```Get-FileHash```. For example, the exact same in-memory string has different byte representations depending on whether you’re encoding with UTF8, UTF16, byte order markers, etc, and these will all give different hashes. If you want to get the same hash as SQL sever you’ll need use the same encoding to get the same byte representation when you write the file…

Comment: I have edited the main post with the code to generate the hash. Please take a look. I don't write to a file, I insert into a column I add to the DataTable

Comment: `StreamWriter` is the key here: if you don't specify an encoding, it defaults to UTF-8. If your string contains no characters outside ASCII, and your DB collation is also ASCII-compatible (the vast majority are) then that will result in the same encoded bytes as `VARCHAR`. Try `$writer = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new($stringAsStream, [System.Text.Encoding]::UnicodeEncoding`, which uses little-endian UTF-16, same as `NVARCHAR` (well, almost -- `NVARCHAR` is technically usually UCS-2, but that doesn't matter in practice if we're not doing linguistic processing).

Comment: @JeroenMostert please post it so I can mark it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code uses `StreamWriter` that uses the default UTF-8 encoding, which matches what you get with hashing a `VARCHAR` -- if you stick to ASCII characters. To hash Unicode instead (and for variation, let's use `SHA256` directly instead of going through `Get-FileHash`, and throw in an emoji so we have to deal with surrogates):

```
$s = "Hello, world! I  you"
$sha256 = [System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256]::Create()
[BitConverter]::ToString(
    $sha256.ComputeHash([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($s))
).Replace("-", "")
```

This yields the same result as

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(64), HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', N'Hello, world! I  you'), 2)
```

Comment: Using your code how can I make it in PowerShell so the 0x appears in front of the hash?

Comment: Well that's a silly format if you ask me, but it's easy enough: `"0x" + [BitConverter]...`